# Android app with AWS analytic integration failed to read awsconfiguration.json

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-studio

I am following the tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-analytics.html)

I am just trying to get a feel for Android development and AWS integration. I setup the basic helloworld Android app following [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/). Then went on to add the AWS components in the first link.

When I get to the "Monitor Analytics" section, my project will build but throw an exception at runtime.

The exception is as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xx.xxxx.wearables_data_receiver.app/com.xx.xxxx.wearables_data_receiver.feature.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read awsconfiguration.json please check that it is correctly formed.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read awsconfiguration.json please check that it is correctly formed.
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.config.AWSConfiguration.readInputJson(AWSConfiguration.java:99)
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.config.AWSConfiguration.<init>(AWSConfiguration.java:83)
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.config.AWSConfiguration.<init>(AWSConfiguration.java:68)
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.config.AWSConfiguration.<init>(AWSConfiguration.java:45)
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.initialize(AWSMobileClient.java:155)
    at com.xx.xxxx.wearables_data_receiver.feature.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
    at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1265)
    at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1241)
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.config.AWSConfiguration.readInputJson(AWSConfiguration.java:88)
```

The line:

```
at com.xx.xxxx.wearables_data_receiver.feature.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
```

Points to the "AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize" call from the tutorial in the first link:

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this, new AWSStartupHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(AWSStartupResult awsStartupResult) {
            System.out.println("AWSMobileClient is instantiated and you are connected to AWS!");
        }
    }).execute();
```

I'm not sure what's going on here, I have tried opening up the file permissions, and placing it in a few different directories but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how to create `awsconfiguration.json` file for push notification ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to missing awsconfiguration.json file.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read awsconfiguration.json please check that it is correctly formed.
```

Could you make sure that you have the `awsconfiguration.json` file placed in the `res/raw` directory and has valid json? If you did the set up using Amplify CLI it should always automatically update the `awsconfiguration.json` file with required information.

Comment: This was definitely the solution to this problem. I had to move the awsconfiguration.json to res/raw directory. Now the application is complaining about missing configurations within that file, but that's a different question I guess. Thanks!

Comment: how to create awsconfiguration.json file for push notification ?